# Python/Flask For Loop ( nested List) in Bootstrap Tab

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

im currently sitting on a problem involving dicts in a list to tabs.
The Values of the keys 'Schnitt_SchnittVF' in the dicts signify the Tab-Names.

I have found a few examples but not really in the way that it helped me to get this thing to work.

Below i posted my template code from within the html file and an example list with the nested Dicts.

Here is the HTML/Jinja Snippet

```
<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12 task-detail-left">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-header">
                                        <h4>Schnittstellen von  {{ rawdataCust[0]['CustMain_Kundenname_Intern'] }} <a href="/index"  style="float: right;" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">Bearbeiten</a></h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                                            {% for row in rawdataSchnitt %}
                                                {% set schnittVF = row['Schnitt_SchnittVF']|string %}
                                                {% set schnitTabName = row['Schnitt_SchnittVF'] ~ "-tab"|string %}
                                                {% set schnittLink = '#' ~ row['Schnitt_SchnittVF']|string %}
                                                <li class="nav-item">
                                                    <a class="nav-link active text-uppercase" id="{{schnittVF}}-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="{{ schnittLink }}" role="tab" aria-controls="{{ schnittVF }}" aria-selected="true">{{ schnittVF }}</a>
                                                </li>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </ul>
                                        {% for row in rawdataSchnitt %}
                                            {% set schnittVF = row['Schnitt_SchnittVF']|string %}
                                            {% set schnitTabName = row['Schnitt_SchnittVF'] ~ "-tab"|string %}
                                            <div class="tab-content" id="{{schnitTabName}}">
                                                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="{{ schnittVF }}" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="{{schnittVF}}-tab">
                                                    <p class="mb-0">
                                                        {{row["Schnitt_AGSIntern"]}}
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p>
                                                        {{row["Schnitt_GVVName"]}}
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p>
                                                        {{row["Schnitt_SchnittVF"]}}
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p>
                                                        {{row["Schnitt_SchnittWerk"]}}
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p>
                                                        {{row["Schnitt_UserExit"]}}
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p>
                                                        {{row["Schnitt_gueltigAb"]}}
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p>
                                                        {{row["Schnitt_gueltigBis"]}}
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>                                            
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Here is an example for the list with nested dicts:

```js
[
  {
    "Schnitt_AGSIntern": "Some_NUMBER", 
    "Schnitt_GVVName": null, 
    "Schnitt_Kundenname_Intern": "Some_NAME", 
    "Schnitt_Mahnst": null, 
    "Schnitt_Mig2Vf": null, 
    "Schnitt_ModulREFX": null, 
    "Schnitt_ModulSoJuHKR": "nein", 
    "Schnitt_SchnittBemerkung": null, 
    "Schnitt_SchnittID": 847, 
    "Schnitt_SchnittMand": "650", 
    "Schnitt_SchnittRueck": "nein", 
    "Schnitt_SchnittSystem": "Production_SAP", 
    "Schnitt_SchnittVF": "NOT_SAP", 
    "Schnitt_SchnittWerk": null, 
    "Schnitt_UserExit": null, 
    "Schnitt_gueltigAb": "02-Jan-00", 
    "Schnitt_gueltigBis": null
  }, 
  {
    "Schnitt_AGSIntern": "Some_NUMBER", 
    "Schnitt_GVVName": null, 
    "Schnitt_Kundenname_Intern": "Some_NAME", 
    "Schnitt_Mahnst": null, 
    "Schnitt_Mig2Vf": null, 
    "Schnitt_ModulREFX": null, 
    "Schnitt_ModulSoJuHKR": "nein", 
    "Schnitt_SchnittBemerkung": null, 
    "Schnitt_SchnittID": 848, 
    "Schnitt_SchnittMand": "650", 
    "Schnitt_SchnittRueck": "nein", 
    "Schnitt_SchnittSystem": "Test_SAP", 
    "Schnitt_SchnittVF": "NOT_SAP", 
    "Schnitt_SchnittWerk": null, 
    "Schnitt_UserExit": null, 
    "Schnitt_gueltigAb": "02-Jan-00", 
    "Schnitt_gueltigBis": null
  }, 
  {
    "Schnitt_AGSIntern": "Some_NUMBER", 
    "Schnitt_GVVName": null, 
    "Schnitt_Kundenname_Intern": "Some_NAME", 
    "Schnitt_Mahnst": "2", 
    "Schnitt_Mig2Vf": null, 
    "Schnitt_ModulREFX": "nein", 
    "Schnitt_ModulSoJuHKR": "ja", 
    "Schnitt_SchnittBemerkung": null, 
    "Schnitt_SchnittID": 849, 
    "Schnitt_SchnittMand": "650", 
    "Schnitt_SchnittRueck": "ja", 
    "Schnitt_SchnittSystem": "Production_SAP", 
    "Schnitt_SchnittVF": "SAP", 
    "Schnitt_SchnittWerk": null, 
    "Schnitt_UserExit": null, 
    "Schnitt_gueltigAb": "01-Jan-07", 
    "Schnitt_gueltigBis": null
  }, 
  {
    "Schnitt_AGSIntern": "Some_NUMBER", 
    "Schnitt_GVVName": null, 
    "Schnitt_Kundenname_Intern": "Some_NAME", 
    "Schnitt_Mahnst": "2", 
    "Schnitt_Mig2Vf": null, 
    "Schnitt_ModulREFX": "nein", 
    "Schnitt_ModulSoJuHKR": "ja", 
    "Schnitt_SchnittBemerkung": null, 
    "Schnitt_SchnittID": 850, 
    "Schnitt_SchnittMand": "650", 
    "Schnitt_SchnittRueck": "ja", 
    "Schnitt_SchnittSystem": "Test_SAP", 
    "Schnitt_SchnittVF": "SAP", 
    "Schnitt_SchnittWerk": null, 
    "Schnitt_UserExit": null, 
    "Schnitt_gueltigAb": "01-Jan-07", 
    "Schnitt_gueltigBis": null
  }
]
```

Here is the routes.py snipped for this route:

```html
@blueprint.route('/cstdetail/<cstAGS>')
@login_required
def cstDetails(cstAGS):

    urlSchnitt = 'http://someServer:5000/cstSchnitt' + '/' + cstAGS
    try:
        uResponseSchnitt = requests.get(urlSchnitt)
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        return "Connection Error"  
    JresponseSchnitt = uResponseSchnitt.text
    rawdataSchnitt = json.loads(JresponseSchnitt)
    #print(rawdata)
    return render_template('customer-detail.html', rawdataSchnitt =rawdataSchnitt)
```

Can someone help me with that, bc im just lost on this one. From my understanding it should work but im probaply just stupid as all hell.... so thanks in advance :).

so long

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. To ask a question here it's required to provide a full minimal example that includes something someone who wanted to help you can run. In your case I'd trim down the json and the html to just 3 elements to provide a simpler example of what you're trying to do and the post that - including the Python code for the flask server.

Comment: @576i Thanks for your comment, i tried to trim down the code and added the specific Flask route. Hope this makes it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you did not use tab Name code below. I think u should remove that code because in every 'for' step that (tabName) code declaring again and again.

```
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                                    {% for row in rawdataSchnitt %}
                                        {% set schnittVF = row['Schnitt_SchnittVF']|string %}
                                        {% set schnitTabName = row['Schnitt_SchnittVF'] ~ "-tab"|string %}
                                        {% set schnittLink = '#' ~ row['Schnitt_SchnittVF']|string %}
                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                            <a class="nav-link active text-uppercase" id="{{schnittVF}}-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="{{ schnittLink }}" role="tab" aria-controls="{{ schnittVF }}" aria-selected="true">{{ schnittVF }}</a>
                                        </li>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
```

And I think you should explain your variable type there (like this => : `<int:number>`):

```
@blueprint.route('/cstdetail/<cstAGS>')
```

If you declare your list named xy:

```
 [
      {
        "Schnitt_AGSIntern": "Some_NUMBER", 
        "Schnitt_GVVName": 1, 
        "Schnitt_Kundenname_Intern": "Some_NAME", 
        "Schnitt_Mahnst": 1, 
        "Schnitt_Mig2Vf": 1, 
        "Schnitt_ModulREFX": 1, 
        "Schnitt_ModulSoJuHKR": "nein", 
        "Schnitt_SchnittBemerkung": 1, 
        "Schnitt_SchnittID": 847, 
        "Schnitt_SchnittMand": "650", 
        "Schnitt_SchnittRueck": "nein", 
        "Schnitt_SchnittSystem": "Production_SAP", 
        "Schnitt_SchnittVF": "NOT_SAP", 
        "Schnitt_SchnittWerk": 1, 
        "Schnitt_UserExit": 1, 
        "Schnitt_gueltigAb": "02-Jan-00", 
        "Schnitt_gueltigBis": 1
      }, 
      {
        "Schnitt_AGSIntern": "Some_NUMBER", 
        "Schnitt_GVVName": 1, 
        "Schnitt_Kundenname_Intern": "Some_NAME", 
        "Schnitt_Mahnst": 1, 
        "Schnitt_Mig2Vf": 1, 
        "Schnitt_ModulREFX": 1, 
        "Schnitt_ModulSoJuHKR": "nein", 
        "Schnitt_SchnittBemerkung": 1, 
        "Schnitt_SchnittID": 848, 
        "Schnitt_SchnittMand": "650", 
        "Schnitt_SchnittRueck": "nein", 
        "Schnitt_SchnittSystem": "Test_SAP", 
        "Schnitt_SchnittVF": "NOT_SAP", 
        "Schnitt_SchnittWerk": 1, 
        "Schnitt_UserExit": 1, 
        "Schnitt_gueltigAb": "02-Jan-00", 
        "Schnitt_gueltigBis": 1
      }, 
      {
        "Schnitt_AGSIntern": "Some_NUMBER", 
        "Schnitt_GVVName": 1, 
        "Schnitt_Kundenname_Intern": "Some_NAME", 
        "Schnitt_Mahnst": "2", 
        "Schnitt_Mig2Vf": 1, 
        "Schnitt_ModulREFX": "nein", 
        "Schnitt_ModulSoJuHKR": "ja", 
        "Schnitt_SchnittBemerkung": 1, 
        "Schnitt_SchnittID": 849, 
        "Schnitt_SchnittMand": "650", 
        "Schnitt_SchnittRueck": "ja", 
        "Schnitt_SchnittSystem": "Production_SAP", 
        "Schnitt_SchnittVF": "SAP", 
        "Schnitt_SchnittWerk": 1, 
        "Schnitt_UserExit": 1, 
        "Schnitt_gueltigAb": "01-Jan-07", 
        "Schnitt_gueltigBis": 1
      }, 
      {
        "Schnitt_AGSIntern": "Some_NUMBER", 
        "Schnitt_GVVName": 1, 
        "Schnitt_Kundenname_Intern": "Some_NAME", 
        "Schnitt_Mahnst": "2", 
        "Schnitt_Mig2Vf": 1, 
        "Schnitt_ModulREFX": "nein", 
        "Schnitt_ModulSoJuHKR": "ja", 
        "Schnitt_SchnittBemerkung": 1, 
        "Schnitt_SchnittID": 850, 
        "Schnitt_SchnittMand": "650", 
        "Schnitt_SchnittRueck": "ja", 
        "Schnitt_SchnittSystem": "Test_SAP", 
        "Schnitt_SchnittVF": "SAP", 
        "Schnitt_SchnittWerk": 1, 
        "Schnitt_UserExit": 1, 
        "Schnitt_gueltigAb": "01-Jan-07", 
        "Schnitt_gueltigBis": 1
      }
    ]
```

if you want to get your list item and item value :

```
    {% for i in xy %}
    {% set item_key = i['Schnitt_AGSIntern'] %}
    
    ...

    <p> item_key </>
    {% endfor %}
```